# Bazel rule is missing dependency for clang's sanitize-blacklist

Tags: clang, bazel, blacklist, sanitizer, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to add ASAN sanitize to our project which uses Bazel and stuck with the following problem. I've added blacklist for sanitize in our bazel.rc

```
build:asan --copt -fsanitize=address
build:asan --linkopt -fsanitize=address
build:asan --copt -fsanitize-blacklist=blacklist.txt
```

but when I build a target I get missing dependency error

```
ERROR: memory/main/BUILD:1:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//main:memory_leak':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'main/memory_leak.cpp':
  'memory/blacklist.txt'
Target //main:memory_leak failed to build
```

It seems that blacklist.txt should be added to the build rule in BUILD file, but we cannot really do that for all gazillion rules we already have. Is there a way to add a global dependency for all rules or something like this?

Comment: How does the `//main:memory_leak` rule's definition look like? Why do you think you have to add blacklist.txt to a gazillion rules?

Comment: `//main:memory_leak` is just an example. We have hundreds or rules in our project.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the C++ toolchain should have the dependency but it is auto-generated.

You can always create a macros to overwrite the default cc_library:

In `tools/build_rules/prelude_bazel`:

`load('@//tools/build_rules:cc.bzl', 'cc_library')`

in `tools/build_rules/cc.bzl`:

`def cc_library(data=[], **kwargs):
  native.cc_library(data = data + ['//memory:blacklist.txt'], **kwargs)`

in `memory/BUILD`:

`exports_files(['blacklist.txt'])`

Also add an empty file `tools/build_rules/BUILD`.

The first file is importing the `cc_library` in the begining of all your file, the second file is defining a new `cc_library` that adds the missing dependency and the third file just expose the 'blacklist.txt' to all the other rules. The last empty file is just to define a package for Bazel that is needed to load the `cc.bzl` file.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example setup for using compile-time suppressions with clang's ASan.

In `.bazelrc`, add `build:asan --define ASAN_ENABLED=true`. In a build file, e.g. the root BUILD file, add

```py
config_setting(
    name = "asan_enabled",
    values = {
        "define": "ASAN_ENABLED=true",
    },
)
```

This is to allow matching on sanitizer use in `select()` .

Now you'll have to add that as a compile-time dependency to your binary to be instrumented (whether that's a `cc_binary` or a `cc_test`). Since it's at compile time, `data` will not work.

The blacklist is treated like a header by clang, so you can put it in `srcs`. However, Bazel allows only files with specific extensions there, so as a [workaround](https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/XE57LP4keoc), move the blacklist to `blacklist.txt.h`.

Like the previous answer suggested, the BUILD file containing the blacklist needs to do `exports_files(["blacklist.txt.h"])`. Finally, define a macro to be used in place of the standard C/C++ rules. For instance, a `cc_binary` replacement would then look like this:

```py
def my_cc_binary(
        *,
        name,
        srcs = [],
        **kwargs):
    native.cc_binary(
        name = name,
        srcs = srcs + select({
            "//:asan_enabled": [
                "//memory:blacklist.txt.h",
            ],
            "//conditions:default": [],
        }),
        **kwargs
    )
```